# How to find particular product quantity in cart?

Tags: magento

I have product id of a product.I want to get the quantity of that product from cart if it is already in cart (if it is there for a logged in user).

If a user(registered) user adds a product to cart leave from site.Then at some time he log in back to the site and add same product to cart.At this time I want to check if same product is there in cart and what is the quantity of product?

```
$cart_m = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

foreach ($cart_m->getAllItems() as $item)
{
    $cart_productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $productQuantity = $item->getProduct()->getQty();//I want to get specific product quantity,If I have product ID

}
```

Comment: if($cart_productId == $theIdIwant) $theQtyIWant = $productQuantity;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cart_m = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$yourProductId = 10;
$needQty = 0; 
foreach ($cart_m->getAllItems() as $item)
{

    $cart_productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $productQuantity = $item->getProduct()->getQty();

    if ($yourProductId == $cart_productId){
        $needQty = $productQuantity;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$needQty){
    echo "This Product Not In Cart";
}else{
    echo $needQty;
}
```

Comment: I used $productQuantity = $item->getQty(); //For getting the product quantity
Thanks for your help.This helped me.

Comment: `$item->getProduct()->getQty()` didn't work, use this instead: `$item->getQty()`

Answer (score 1):

You can get product quantity without looping all items:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$_item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
$qty = $_item->getQty();
```

Comment: You get a Fatal error (Fatal error: Call to a member function getQty() on boolean) if product is not in cart. You'd better use: 

$_quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$_item = $_quote ? $_quote->getItemByProduct($_product) : false;
$qty = $_item ? $_item->getQty() : 0;